# Classic ASP send CURL push message to parse.com

Tags: php, json, curl, asp-classic

I'm trying to send a push message to parse.com from a Classic ASP based website. Below is my code, and beneath that the PHP equivalent. No error message. (Replaced client data with xxx.) Any suggestions?

ASP code:

```vb
<%
Set xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") 
xmlHttp.Open "POST", strUrl, False
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "X-Parse-Application-Id", "xxx"
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "xxx"
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
xmlHttp.Send "{ ""data"": [ { ""channel"": ""xxx"" }, { ""alert"": ""Test Push"" }, { ""sound"": ""push.caf"" } ] }"
set xmlHttp = Nothing 
%>
```

PHP code:

```php
<?php
$APPLICATION_ID = "xxx";
$REST_API_KEY = "xxx";
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';
$data = array(
'channel' => 'xxx',
'data' => array(
    'alert' => 'Test Push',
    'sound' => 'push.caf',
),
);
$_data = json_encode($data);
$headers = array(
'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data),
);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_exec($curl);
?>
```

Comment: i always find it handy to write out some logging to a text file, and then you can see where your code runs to, and analyse the content of variables

Comment: JSON strings does not equal. Compare string of JSON in the ASP code with output `json_encode($data)`

Answer (score 1):

Looks as though your JSON is not equivalent (as [@Kul-Tigin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893670/kul-tigin) pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562275/classic-asp-send-curl-push-message-to-parse-com#comment36155807_23562275)).

Looking at your PHP JSON object the Classic ASP should be;

```vb
xmlHttp.Send "[ { ""channel"": ""xxx"" }, { ""data"": [ { ""alert"": ""Test Push"" }, { ""sound"": ""push.caf"" } ] } ]"
```

If you break it down (using your PHP JSON object);

- `$data` is an array (*containing*) `[]`

  - `channel` is an object `{ ""channel"": ""xxx"" }`
  - `data` is an array (*containing*) `{ ""data"": [] }`

    - `alert` is an object `{ ""alert"": ""Test Push"" }`
    - `sound` is an object `{ ""sound"": ""push.caf"" }`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is all your code, the variable strUrl is not set to anything.

Add:

```
strUrl = "https://api.parse.com/1/push"
```

As your first line.

Comment: Blimey, good spot. Haven't looked at this for a while, but if it's that obvious I'll be administering myself a good kicking.