# Problem adding JSON content to WinHttpRequest POST request in classic ASP

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic, winhttprequest

I am trying to retrieve data using an NHS API and the instructions are as follows...

```
Endpoint        https://api.nhs.uk/service-search/search?api-version=1
Method      POST
Headers     Content-Type: application/json
subscription-key: MYKEYHERE
Body        {
    "filter": "OrganisationTypeID eq 'PHA'",
    "orderby": "OrganisationName",
    "top": 25,
    "skip": 0,
    "count": true
}
```

Following the answer here [How can I post data using cURL in asp classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462580/how-can-i-post-data-using-curl-in-asp-classic/37462944#37462944) I tried this...

```
<%
Dim http: Set http = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
StrFilter = "OrganisationTypeID eq 'PHA'"
StrFilter = Server.UrlEncode(StrFilter)
Dim url: url = "https://api.nhs.uk/service-search/search?api-version=1"
Dim data: data = "filter=" & StrFilter & "&orderby=OrganisationName&top=25&skip=0&count=true"
With http
  Call .Open("POST", url, False)
  Call .SetRequestHeader("subscription-key", "MYKEYHERE")
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  Call .Send(data)
End With
If Left(http.Status, 1) = 2 Then
  'Request succeeded with a HTTP 2xx response, do something...
  Response.Write http.responseText
Else
  'Output error
  Call Response.Write("Server returned: " & http.Status & " " & http.StatusText)
End If
%>
```

...but this gives me "Server returned: 400 Bad Request". It's almost certainly a case of me not knowing how to do this properly. Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the API expects an `application/json` body, so you need to pass that instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

You can build the [JSON up as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23563354/692942) but it needs to conform to a JSON structure or you will likely get an `HTTP 400 Bad Request` again.

Replace `data` with;

```
Dim data: data = "{ ""filter"": ""OrganisationTypeID eq 'PHA'"", ""orderby"": ""OrganisationName"", ""top"": 25, ""skip"": 0, ""count"": true }"
```

You could also [use some existing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38188074/692942) to build and parse JSON for you.

Personally I'd recommend - [JSON object class by RCDMK](https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON)

Comment: ok. I have no idea how to do that, sorry.
Is Call .SetRequestBody("parameter", "value") a thing?
I tried passing the body values like that instead but just get a 500 error

Comment: @Shred You just need to pass `Send()` the correctly formatted string, added an example of what `data` should look like.

Comment: Yup, that worked. Those curly brackets are important! Thanks again Lankymart, that should be all I need to get this going.

Comment: @Shred yep, the curly brackets are important when it comes to [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) data.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem

```
url="https://test/xyzapi/api/Account/login"
Dim oXMLHttp
dim auth_token
Set oXMLHttp=Server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
oXMLHttp.setOption 2, 13056
oXMLHttp.open "POST", url,false
oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/json"
oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; 
Windows NT 5.0)"
strJSONToSend ="{""Username"":""test"",""Password"":""123456""}"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).